# Bayesian Decision Theory - Self Study

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, naive-bayes, decision-theory

Consider a naive Bayes classier with a binary class $Y ∈ {0, 1}$ and three binary features $X_1, X_2, X_3$ ∈
{0, 1}. You are given a set $D$ of $n$ training examples, i.e.

D={$(x^{(1)}_1, x^{(1)}_2, x^{(1)}_3, y^{(1)}), . . . ,(x^{(n)}_1, x^{(n)}_2, x^{(n)}_3, y^{(n)})$}.

Suppose for some example the posterior is $P(Y = 1 | X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, X_3 = x_3) = p$ and assume that there is a cost $c_m$ for misclassication (that is, classifying a sample with label 1 as
having label 0 or vice versa). For each prediction you have the choice between trusting the naive
Bayes classier or asking a human expert with cost $c_h < c_m$, who is 100% accurate.

Which of
these two choices minimizes the expected cost as a function of p?

**My solution:**

- $ \begin{equation}
     \text{Conditional distribution $P(Y=y|X)$}  = 
      \begin{cases}
        p, & \text{if}\ y=1 \\
        1-p, & \text{if y= -1}
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation}$
- Action set A = $\{-1,1,H\}$
- $ \begin{equation}
     \text{Cost-function $C(y,a)$} = 
      \begin{cases}
        c_m . \mathbf{1}_{y \neq a}, & \text{if a $\in$ {1,-1}}\  \\
       c_h  & \text{if a = H}
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation}$

In the Bayesian optimal decision framework we want to pick the action which minimizes the expected loss:

$a^* = argmin_{a \in A}   \mathbb{E}[C(y,a)|x]= argmin_{a \in A} \sum_y (c_m.\mathbb{1}[y \neq a]\mathbb{1}[a \neq H]+c_h.\mathbb{1}[H=a])P(y|x)$

By analyzing each cost separately:

$\begin{equation}
   \text{ $\mathbb{E}[C(y,a)|x]$}  = 
    \begin{cases}
      (1-p).c_m, & \text{if a=1} \\
      p.c_m, & \text{if a= -1}  \\
c_h, & \text{if a= H}  \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$

But I dont know how to conclude from here which make me doubt about my solution. Can somebody help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like we are all in the same class:)))  Here is the answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296230/exercise-should-we-trust-our-naive-bayes-or-a-human-guru